# How i can edit Elysium Theme from current project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

How i can **edit** [Ellysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/) Theme from current project?
Need to edit all colors and other feaches! 
I can't find place in my project, where i can edit soure code of current theme. [this](http://elysium.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/10074#146162)
All works great, but in standart Elysium controls.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what the exact filename is for the ellysium theme Resource Dictionary but if you open you App.xaml you should find its path reference under your Merged Dictionaries to find it. Once you have that, you can just open the file and edit the values accordingly.

If you're using Expression Blend this tasks is even easier since you should have the Resource Dictionary listed under your "Resources" tab (top right by default) and can individually edit each Style Template from there. Hope this helps.

(You might encourage them to address this under their actual CodePlex project since last time I checked all it had for Documentation was something like "Coming Soon" or something like that...)